# Team Foundation Server Compliance

Tags: tfs

We will be setting up Team Foundation Server shortly and I would like to know if there is any way to ensure compliance on the development workstations that will be using TFS as far as CALs and such.

P.S. I apologize if this is the wrong forum... wasnt sure where to post.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by compliance? enforced check-in rules?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Workgroup Edition from MSDN then the server will enforce the 5-user limit.  Those aren't technically CALs, though -- you're allowed to connect without purchasing any special client licenses.

I'm not aware of any tools for tracking CALs on the standard edition.  It's fairly straightforward, though: when you purchase software for a developer workstation, make sure every TFS user gets either Pro + CAL or a Team Edition.

Another tricky part of license compliance is making sure that non-CAL users who are allowed to access the work item tracking system only review their own bugs; systemwide access requires a CAL.  (See the revised TFS 2008 licensing whitepapers for details).  Good news is that the WIWA tool does most of the heavy lifting for you.  You simply need to restrict access to the regular TSWA website to a licensed group of users, and open up WIWA for everyone else.

WIWA is included with [TSWA SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=3ECD00BA-972B-4120-A8D5-3D38311893DE&displaylang=en) and later.